# Remove two unnecessary permissions in the consent screen

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth

We are submitting an add-on for Google Sheets, the add-on is not in the marketplace yet. The follows is the current APIs & Services of the add-on. All the APIs and Services are not necessary.

```
BigQuery API                    
BigQuery Storage API                    
Cloud Datastore API                 
Cloud Logging API                   
Cloud Monitoring API                    
Cloud SQL                   
Cloud Storage                   
Cloud Storage API                   
Cloud Trace API                 
Google Cloud APIs                   
Google Cloud Storage JSON API                   
Google Workspace Marketplace SDK                    
Service Management API                  
Service Usage API
```

We run the add-on in the test mode to make the demo video of OAuth verification, here is the consent screen:

[image]

"See, edit, create, and delete all your Google Sheets spreadsheets" and "Display and run third-party web content in prompts and sidebars inside Google applications" are necessary for the add-in. However, "See, edit, create, and delete all your Google Docs documents" and "View and manage your forms in Google Drive" are unnecessary.

Does anyone know how to remove the two unnecessary permissions?

PS: The scopes we are requesting at the moment:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be a little confused.  The images you have shown from Google cloud console only show the scopes you intend to use to the verification team. They have nothing to do with what is shown in the OAuth consent screen.

The scopes shown in the OAuth consent screen come directly from your code.  You have added scopes to your code these are the scopes that are displayed to the user.

If you want to remove one or more you need to check your code and remove them there.

You probably have these two in your code some where. Remove them.

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms

They seam to be part of the [Apps Script API, v1](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#script) scopes so i would check your app script project to see if you don't have some extra permissions requested.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But my code is quite simple. It opens a modeless dialog which hosts a website which can interact with contents in the workbook. I don't see where is related to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents or https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms

Comment: Well all I can say is Google doesn't randomly add scopes to the consent screen it's there because you have Add it.   Go look again

Comment: I think i have figured out the problem: I removed a comment `// Or DocumentApp or FormApp.` in the code, and the two permissions disappeared. But there is one more question: I request `.../auth/script.external_request` (the website hosted in the modeless dialog connects to external service). But in the consent screen, there is no `Connect to an external service`, is it normal?

Comment: I posted a new question to draw attention: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77469323

Comment: external service are systems outside of Googles control. For example if you were connecting to an outside rest api or reading from a website.

Comment: Google does automatically add scopes based on the code in apps script.

Comment: @TheMaster really which ones? I would love to test it.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo I meant this comment: `Google doesn't randomly add scopes to the consent screen it's there because you have Add it.`  In Apps script, although scopes maybe explicitly added, it is not required. The scopes needed are automatically inferred from the code. In OP's case, it was just a comment: `//DocumentApp` added `/auth/documents` scope automatically to the "consent screen".