# auth/script.external_request and "Connect to an external service"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth

We are submitting an add-on for Google Sheets, the add-on is not in the marketplace yet. The add-on will open a modeless dialog which hosts a website, the website will read data in the workbook, send it to external service, get results, and write them back to the workbook.

So the scopes we are requesting at the moment in the console are as follows. It includes `.../auth/script.external_request`

[image]

On the other side, when we run the add-on in the test mode to make the demo video of OAuth verification, the follows is the permissions in the consent screen. There is no `Connect to an external service`.

[image]

Does anyone know:

- should I request `.../auth/script.external_request` in the console?
- if I should request that scope, is it OK to not have `Connect to an external service` in the consent screen?
- if I have to show `Connect to an external service` in the consent screen, how could I add it?

Comment: The url of the consent screen(in Firefox, if you can't see in chrome) - does it have the `external_request` scope listed?